# Can't boot MacBook Pro 13" (mid 2010)

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, startup

The problem occurred after installing the **update SMC** 1.6 on Apple - **OS X Mountain Lion**:

- First for a long time was a white screen and **noisy cooler**
- After the system battery icon was crossed out and the indicator on the left side of macbook does not show anything and everything worked cooler at high speed (he was cold macbook)
- After reboot appeared [crossed circle](http://km.support.apple.com/library/APPLE/APPLECARE_ALLGEOS/TS1411/TS1411_1.gif) and the system has stopped running
- I took out the hard drive and connected via a USB adapter to the same Macbook pro and have to boot from my hard drive - as a result the system has booted and gave to make a full backup timemachine
- My macbook does not boot with any device (Hdd, Usb flash, DVD, other HDD) while on other laptops these devices make it possible to boot

  Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you Mac doesn't detect an OS on the drive (or the OS is corrupted...) at least, that's what the crossed circle means. It's trying to boot, but it's missing some files in the System folder.

There are some solutions to this issue:

If your MacBook Pro is still able to "*boot*" (meaning, it reacts when pressing the power button):

- Select your start-up disk:
  Hold the <kbd>alt</kbd> button immediately after pressing the power button until some drives appear on the screen. Now select you Macintosh HD to start up from.
- Try to force start from your system folder:
  Press the <kbd>X</kbd> immediately after pressing the power button. It will force the Mac to start up from your Mac OS X. If this works, go to System Preferences and make sure your folder is the System Folder.
- Boot from a bootable drive (like a [Mountain Lion Startup USB disk](http://www.cultofmac.com/180925/how-to-make-a-bootable-disk-or-usb-drive-of-os-x-mountain-lion/)) and re-install the OS. I sure hope you have a back-up of your files...

If your MacBook Pro isn't able to "*boot*" (same meaning as above):

- Unplug the drive and connect it to another computer. Try to access the drive as an external hard drive, take a backup of your files and format the drive.
  After that, plug it back in your MacBook Pro and use the last bullet of above to re-install your OS.

Since I've been there and struggling for many hours to get things working, I think of myself as a semi-expert :)
So, if you've any questions at all, feel free to ask.

Comment: I visited Apple service centre and after some tests they said me that on my macbook I need to replace logicboard(motherboard). But it'll cost me more than $500. As for me it's very interesting situation: Apple made update for Mac OS X (SMC 1.6), I got this update and after that I have to pay money for new motherboard :)

Comment: That's far from normal... Did you drop the MacBook by accident? Have you tried my steps above?

Comment: Two days ago I have installed Mac Os X 10.6.4 but when the system had started working I saw my desktop it was at least 2-3 sec, after that macbook went to sleep mode.  I pressed any key macbook and system started working, but without lighting screen. I used bright lamp and saw that all shortcuts and indicators (like wifi, battery etc.) have appeared on my desktop. After 2-3 sec macbook went to sleep mode again. Pressing on buttons and light from lamp gave me possibility to done update to 10.6.5. But at the end situation was not changed.

Comment: When I boot macbook with using install DVD, I can use all utilities (disk utility, network util etc.) and macbook don't goes to sleep mode and screen has light.
In my opinion reason of this - not correct installation latest EFI or SMC updates. I tried to install EFI update 2.0 for 10.6.5, but system showed me that I can't do this update.
I'll try to find some way to make EFI update, maybe this would help me solve this problem.
P.S. answer from Applle support: Our updates can't to break your macbook... it's just coincidence. Probability theory it's just mystification :)

Comment: I've found this post http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/82066/osx-10-8-2-update-wrong-smc?answertab=active#tab-top I have this (1.68f99 instead 1.62f7) version SMC too.

Comment: http://joxi.ru/55smUdg5CbBBHLyMEFs this is info about my MacBook Pro 13" (mid 2010) MC374ll/A. As you can see I had SMC version 1.68f99 instead 1.62f7 :)