# osx 10.8.2 update - wrong smc

Tags: macbook-pro

the last update caused a white screen with a grey symbol. OSX 10.8.2 doesn't start.
I have a MacBook Pro Mid 2010
I can do nothing. Recovery, Internet Installation, everything failed.
I found out that the wrong SMC Version was installed. It installed 1.68f99 and i need 1.62f7 (SMC 1.6)
The boot ROM Version is right.
What can I do?
Can somebody help me?

BR Stefan

Comment: Have a look at this article: http://support.apple.com/kb/HT3964?viewlocale=en_US&locale=en_US , specially the section about resetting the System Management Controller. If that fails and if you have an Apple Store near you, ask there for advice, otherwise, bring your Mac to an Apple authorized reseller for repair...

Comment: "Congratulations" you are not alone! I have exactly problem. http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/81975/cant-boot-macbook-pro-13-mid-2010
We should pressing Apple and maybe they help us.

Comment: I found this article: http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1237 We can see that both links 1.62f7 and 1.68f99 lead us to page: http://support.apple.com/kb/DL1626 I've had conversation with support and they sad me that 2 accidents not enough to do something :) We should just wait, in my opinion after few days or weeks we can meet new members in our "Update SMC 1.6 = Broken Macbook Pro 13" middle 2010" club!

Comment: You solved the problem? If - "yes", how? You solved the problem? If - "yes", how? Let me know please.

Answer (score 1):

Incorrect firmware could be something that you can not recover from and result in a trip to the Genius Bar or another authorized service center where they can work with engineering to determine if user error or a bug resulted in the incorrect firmware loading or if they need to re-flash the EFI or just replace the logic board to get back to the proper / supported version of firmware for your hardware.

In the past - when a firmware revision has been problematic and there are reasons for a substantial portion of the user base to want to regress to an earlier version of firmware, Apple has released [firmware recovery tools](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT2213)to the public. In your case, I don't see public versions of the firmware you seek, so these may only distributed to service centers and not end users or not something Apple has released a tool to remedy. You still can seek service options since firmware is something that can be exchanged with a part swap as part of a repair.